# In SwiftUI, how to create a non View object only once inside a child View

Tags: swiftui, view

I want to link to a view that contains a non-view object - created once per user tap of the "Start" link - that is dependent on data selected by the user.  The code below is as close as I've gotten.  QuestionView.init is called as soon as HomeView appears, and again every time you select a new value for Highest Number, thus creating the Question object repeatedly, which is what I'm trying to avoid.  I want to only create the Question object one time - when the user taps on the "Start" link.

I've tried many different approaches.  It feels like I am stuck problem solving from an imperative UI oriented approach, instead of the new-for-me declarative approach of SwiftUI.   Perhaps there's a bridge I'm missing from the state-driven approach of Views to the more familiar-to-me non-view objects, like my Question object I want to create only once.

```
struct Question {
  let value1: Int
  let value2: Int
  let answer: Int

  init(_ highestNumber: Int) {
    print("Question.init \(highestNumber)")
    value1 = Int.random(in: 1...highestNumber)
    value2 = Int.random(in: 1...highestNumber)
    answer = value1 * value2
  }

  var prompt: String {
    "\(value1) x \(value2) = ?"
  }
}

struct HomeView: View {
  @State var highestNumber: Int = 12

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      Picker("Highest Number", selection: $highestNumber) {
        ForEach(4...12, id: \.self) { Text(String($0)) }
      }
      .pickerStyle(.wheel)
      NavigationLink(destination: QuestionView(highestNumber: $highestNumber)) {
        Text("Start")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct QuestionView: View {
  @Binding var highestNumber: Int
  @State var question: Question

  init(highestNumber: Binding<Int>) {
    print("QuestionView.init")
    self._highestNumber = highestNumber
    question = Question(highestNumber.wrappedValue)
  }

  var body: some View {
    Text(question.prompt)
    Button("I got it") {
      question = Question(highestNumber)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `onAppear`?

Comment: Yes.  If I initialize question, as nil, and then build it once in onAppear, then it crashes because onAppear is called after body is called, which is dependent on question not being nil.

Comment: Okay, but that should be easily coded around using `if let` or something like that

Comment: Yes, technically that does work.  I have approached it that way.  But I am hopeful there is a better way - it feels like a work around to have a big chunk of my view wrapped in an if let.

Comment: Encapsulate it into a child view -- no reason that it needs to have a big chunk wrapped. Display one view if there's a question, and an EmptyView if not.